# Ionic 4/5 - Error : Routing : When Tabs Page used as a component

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic4

Hey Guys I am facing the routing problem when I used Tabs as a component.

What I have done is that, I made a tabs page and a shared.Module.Ts file.

In shared.Module.Ts file I Import the tabspage, as I want to use this tabs in many of the pages.
Tabs page imported success fully in other pages, but I stucked in Routing , It gives me a error

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'home/address'

Please help me out here is my code

**Shared.module.ts file**

```
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { CommonModule } from "@angular/common";
import { TabsPage } from "../pages/tabs/tabs.page";

@NgModule({
    declarations: [TabsPage],
    exports: [TabsPage],
    imports: [CommonModule],
})
export class SharedModule {}
```

**Tabs Page**

```
<ion-tab-bar slot="bottom">
  <ion-tab-button tab="home">
    <ion-icon name="triangle"></ion-icon>
    <ion-label>Tab 1</ion-label>
  </ion-tab-button>

  <ion-tab-button tab="myaccount">
    <ion-icon name="ellipse"></ion-icon>
    <ion-label>Tab 2</ion-label>
  </ion-tab-button>

  <ion-tab-button tab="address">
    <ion-icon name="square"></ion-icon>
    <ion-label>Tab 3</ion-label>
  </ion-tab-button>
</ion-tab-bar>
```

**tabs-routing.module.ts**

```
    import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { RouterModule, Routes } from "@angular/router";
import { AddressPage } from "../address/address.page";
import { HomePage } from "../home/home.page";
import { MyaccountPage } from "../myaccount/myaccount.page";
import { TabsPage } from "./tabs.page";

const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: "tabs",
        component: TabsPage,
        children: [
            {
                path: "home",
                children: [
                    {
                        path: "",
                        component: HomePage,
                    },
                ],
            },
            {
                path: "myaccount",
                children: [
                    {
                        path: "",
                        component: MyaccountPage,
                    },
                ],
            },
            {
                path: "wallet",
                children: [
                    {
                        path: "",
                        component: AddressPage,
                    },
                ],
            },
            {
                path: "",
                redirectTo: "/tabs/home",
                pathMatch: "full",
            },
        ],
    },
    {
        path: "",
        redirectTo: "/tabs/home",
        pathMatch: "full",
    },
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule],
    })
export class TabsPageRoutingModule {}
```

Please Help me. Thanks

Comment: `children: [
          {
            path: '',
            loadChildren: '../tab1/tab1.module#Tab1PageModule'
          }
        ]` try somehitng like this.

Comment: @NajamUsSaqib 

I have already tried out that one but didn't works...